# Unsupervised classification methods available

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm doing a research which involves "unsupervised classification".
Basically I have a trainSet and I want to cluster data in X number of classes in unsupervised way. Idea is similar to what k-means  does.

Let's say

Step1)
featureSet is a [1057x10] matrice and I want to cluster them into 88 clusters.

Step2)
Use previously calculated classes to compute how does the testData is classified

Question
-Is it possible to do it with SVM or N-N ? Anything else ?
-Any other recommendations ?

Comment: Have you actually tried using k-means? It seems well suited to the problem.

Comment: Hi
Idid it actually.
But I need to do same thing with a different method to compare results.
Any recommendations?

Comment: SVM is supervised, not unsupervised, so it is not ok for what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many clustering algorithms out there, and the web is awash with information on them and sample implementations. A good starting point is the Wikipedia entry on cluster analysis [Cluster_analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

As you have a working k-means implementation, you could try one of the many variants to see if they yeild better results (k-means++ perhaps, seeing as you mentioned SVM). If you want a completely different approach, have a look at Kohonen Maps - also called Self Organising Feature Maps. If that looks too tricky, a simple hierarchical clustering would be easy to implement (find the nearest two items, combine, rinse and repeat).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic clustering problem. Neither SVMs or neural networks are going to be able to directly solve this problem. You can use either approach for [dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_reduction), for example to embed your 10-dimensional data in two-dimensional space, but they will not put the data into clusters for you.

There are a huge number of clustering algorithms besides k-means. If you wanted a contrasting approach, you might want to try an [agglomerative clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Agglomerative_hierarchical_clustering) algorithm. I don't know what kind of computing environment you are using, but I quite like [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and [this (very) short guide on clustering](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html).